# I have a shell script, which export one environment file, which itself export the second environment, where declared and export global variable

Tags: shell

I have Unix shell script, which uses some environment files. In environment file I see the line:

```
. /export/applications/ibm6000/dte/sh/nyggmfiss.env
```

when I opened  nyggmfiss.env   file, I see variable

```
${__DTEENV}
```

I checked other environment files and one of them has a line

```
export __DTEENV=${0}
```

Does somebody know what is $(0)? Does it come from the script, which export one environment file, or it is a name of environment file, which has "export another environment file?

Comment: `${0}` is the same as `$0`; `$(0)` is the output of a command with the name `0`.

Answer (score 1):

man bash:

```
 $0 is set to the name of the file
```

Comment: Which file? I don't have any input file in the script. Also it is UNIX and $0 is the name of the script, which is running. It is Korn shell, not bash

Comment: you're right: the scriptfile.

Comment: you mean the script name, correct?

Answer (score 0):

`${0}` is the outer shell script that started the shell process by having `#!/bin/yourshell` (the shebang line) as its first line.
If there is no outer shell script (when you enter the `.` command on the command line) then `${0}` is your shell.

The concept of `${0}` does not apply to sourced "environment files", so it remains unchanged when `.` commands (source commands) are executed in the .